# Не собирается yandex phantom

Tags: c++, яндекс-танк

Скачал исходники веб-сервера phantom для яндекс.танка.
При сборке ругается

```
    In file included from phantom/io_monitor/io_monitor.C:10:0:
    phantom/io_monitor/../stat.H: In constructor ‘phantom::stat_id_t::stat_id_t()’:
    phantom/io_monitor/../stat.H:20:43: error: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Werror=overflow]
      inline stat_id_t() throw() : res_no(~0ULL) { }
                                               ^
    phantom/io_monitor/../stat.H: In member function ‘phantom::stat_id_t::operator bool() const’:
    phantom/io_monitor/../stat.H:21:47: error: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Werror=type-limits]
      inline operator bool() const { return res_no != ~0ULL; }
                                                   ^
    cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
    opts.mk:48: recipe for target 'phantom/io_monitor/io_monitor.s.o' failed
    make: *** [phantom/io_monitor/io_monitor.s.o] Error 1
```

Поскольку очень далек от С++ и от системного программирования, мне кажется ~0ULL какой-то хитровыдуманной заменой NULL?

версия gcc 4.9

uname

3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) i686 GNU/Linux

**UPD**

Требуется 64-битная система для нормальной работы яндекс.танк

Comment: `~0ULL` - это `~`, применяемая к `0`  типа `unsigned long long` (`ULL`). Судя по `pae` - у вас 32-битная платформа? Если да, то вот оно и не вписывается в обычный `unsigned`.

Comment: Теперь понятно, что это.
Выходит нужно отключить `all warnings being treated as errors`, для того, чтобы это собралось?

Comment: Можно попробовать, если нет жёстких завязок на разрядность может и заработает. А не проще поставить готовое? Пакеты у них [есть](https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installation-deb-packages), но есть ли там 32 - не проверял.

Comment: Да, платформа 32-битная.

Comment: Пакеты не ставятся, не находит путь. Изменил на 0UL вроде собирается

Comment: Сделал апгрейд до 64-бит. Собралось без проблем.

Answer (score 2):

`0` - нуль
`0ULL` - нуль типа `unsigned long long`
`~0ULL` - применение оператора `~` к нулю типа `unsigned long long`..